# Citymaps questions on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, citymaps

I have some new questions in today's citymaps development.

1. In the Android studio,if I develop the code for citymap, there are always no logs showing but for others that does not happen. Why?
2. According to the `citymaps` official website, to create a map instance with `CitymapsMapFragment`, but in the sample project which citymaps provides, it uses `SupportCitymapsMpaFragment` ,What is the difference between them?
3. When the map is loading complete, is it automatically positioning to the current position or some other default position? Where is it?
4. If I open the GPS location，I can locate to the current position and show a blue arrow quickly, but too much power consumption,are there any other location way like network or base station location?

Code follows:

```
CitymapsMapFragment fragment = (CitymapsMapFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);    
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.setMapViewListener(this);
}
```

I did not find the fragment have the method `setMapViewListener` but `setMapViewReadyListener`,does it right?

Other code:

```
CitymapsMapView mapView = new CitymapsMapView(this, options, this);
```

When I add animate in additional methods like this：

```
mapView.setMapPosition(position, 300, new MapViewAnimationListener() {    
    @Override   
    public void onAnimationEnd(boolean completed) {       
        Log.d("SomeApp", "Move Complete!");    
    } 
});
```

the project fails and exits,I tried to surround the code with `try-catch` block to catch exception for purpose, but nothing shows in logcat view. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am developer on the Citymaps project.  I will do my best to answer all your questions

1) If you are not receiving log statements, this is likely an issue with your own application, IDE, or device configuration.  In our own application, which uses the Citymaps SDK, we have no issues with logging.

2) Prior to using the Citymaps SDK, it is highly advisable that you familiarize yourself with fragments, but the short version is that `SupportCitymapsMapFragment` extends from the `Fragment` class in the v4 support library.

3) It is up to you to set the default position the map.

4) If you create a class which implements from the `LocationSource` interface, and then call `mapView.setLocationSource`, you can modify the behaviors of the map's location services.  For an example, have a look at CitymapsLocationSource.java, which is the default implementation for this interface used by the SDK.

As for the exception you are having, you have not provided nearly enough information.  Please show a stack trace, and I may be able to help.

Thank you for using our SDK, feel free to post again with any more questions.